# sql rows into columns pivot table

Tags: sql, select, pivot, teradata

I have sql view like this:

```
id date_from  date_to
1  2005-01-05 2005-05-10
1  2005-01-05 2005-05-10
1  2005-01-05 2005-05-10
2  2005-01-01 2006-08-31
2  2010-01-01 2010-06-30
3  2005-01-01 2005-06-30
```

And I want to write sql statement which returns:

```
1 2005-01-05 2005-05-10 2005-01-05 2005-05-10 2005-01-05 2005-05-10
2 2005-01-01 2006-08-31 2010-01-01 2010-06-30 NULL       NULL
3 2005-01-01 2005-06-30 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this - MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer...? Also, are you ever going to want more than three date_from, date_to pairs per id?

Comment: From the fact that you put "pivot" in your title and tags, you obviously already had one idea, and apparently it didn't work. What went wrong with it? And, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Teradata. View can have more than 3 dates in same cases but I want use 3 newest dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to Mark's question will help.

> Which RDBMS is this - MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer...? Also, are you ever
>   going to want more than three date_from, date_to pairs per id?

using t-sql, I explicitly handle 3 levels. If you want it to be dynamic, you need to create the query dynamically.

```
DECLARE @staging TABLE
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    date_from datetime NOT NULL,
    date_to datetime NOT NULL,
    step int
)

INSERT INTO @staging
SELECT id, date_from, date_to,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_from, date_to)
FROM tblTemp

-- below is static for 3 levels, make below dynamic to match what you want
SELECT t1.id, t1.date_from, t1.date_to, t2.date_from, t2.date_to, t3.date_from, t3.date_to
FROM @staging t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @staging t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.step = 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @staging t3 ON t2.id = t3.id AND t3.step = 3
WHERE t1.step = 1
```

Test @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9daae/4/0

Comment: Thanks, it looks great. I will try it tomorrow on Teradata.

Comment: @PetrNovák, I am new to teradata. I just confirmed that virtually everything above will work. The only questionable part is the temp table.

Comment: You can declare the temp table as a VOLATILE TABLE in Teradata which will be created in the user's SPOOL space.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're most recent questions have been related to MySQL, I'll assume you want a MySQL solution.

If you know the max number of potential date ranges, then you can use MAX and CASE.  However, you have to have a row counter since you don't have any other unique identifier (I'd actually recommend adding that to your view since you mention this is a view).  Here it is though:

```
SELECT Id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN date_from END) date_from1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN date_to END) date_to1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN date_from END) date_from2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN date_to END) date_to2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 3 THEN date_from END) date_from3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 3 THEN date_to END) date_to3
FROM (
  SELECT 
      id, 
      @running:=if(@previous=id,@running,0) + 1 as row_number,
      @previous:=id,
      date_from, date_to
  FROM YourView 
      JOIN    (SELECT @previous := 0) r
    ORDER BY id, date_from, date_to
) t
GROUP BY Id
```

If you don't know the maximum number of date ranges, then you won't be able to do this with a single SQL statement.  Instead, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

I'll assume you can add the row_number to your View and here is a close example:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = ', 
      row_number, 
      ' THEN date_from END) date_from', 
      row_number)
  ),
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = ',  
      row_number, 
      ' THEN date_to END) date_to',  
      row_number)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM YourView;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  ID, ', 
                   @sql, ' 
                   FROM    YourView
                   GROUP   BY ID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Best of luck.