# split row_number() over partition over multiple columns

Tags: sql, teradata, row-number

I have a query which uses row_number() over partition.
When the result comes out it looks like

```
Product         Row_Number         Price
A               1                  25
A               2                  20
A               3                  15
B               1                  100
B               2                  10
B               3                  2
```

I want to get the result to show over columns like

```
Product      Row1         Row2        Row3      price1       price2       price3
A            1            2           3         25           20           15
B            1            2           3         100          10           2
```

Should I use something like rank()???

I'm using Teradata

Comment: [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to do this in SQL, I'm working in Teradata

Comment: Take a look at how to pivot using Teradata [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837996/sql-rows-into-columns-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two more window functions to get the 2nd and 3rd highest price, this should run in the same STAT-step as your current ROW_NUMBER, so there's no additional overhead:

```
select
   product,
   price as Price1,
   min(price)
   over (partition by product
         order by price desc
         rows between 1 following and 1 following) as Price2,
   min(price)
   over (partition by product
         order by price desc
         rows between 2 following and 2 following) as Price3
from tab
qualify 
   row_number() 
   over (partition by product
         order by price desc) = 1
```

Comment: When I try to apply this I get an message saying 'something expected between the word 'Price2' and the 'over' keyword

Comment: Argh, this happens when you do cut&paste, fixed it.

Comment: I put 'price2' before 'over'. So it's coming with results now. However, I just get the max everytime. Cause qualify only asks for the top result. I need to get the three different results. Is that possible? @dnoeth

Comment: This code should return the top three prices if you use it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I just give sort direction for each sort parameter , and then , it works , very fine. No Partition is used.

```
SELECT TOP (5) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SCHEME ASC,APPLICATION_DATE DESC,TRANSACTION_REF_NO ASC,APPLICATION_STATUS DESC)
```